# Study of the input variables in a regression setting

Tags: regression

I want to learn a regression model between regressors `X` and a variable `y`.

I would like to know what kind of study of `X` variables is advised before learning the regression model.

So far, I have plotted variables and I have done a PCA of them.

Answer (score 0):

Remember you are interested in $Pr(Y|X)$ and not $Pr(X)$ or $Pr(Y,X)$. Therefore there is nothing to do on $X$. But if the number of $X$ columns are large then you might want to reduce that by a PCA. If you use a technique that is sensitive to the units of the $X$ columns (LASSO, Ridge regression), you might  want to scale $X$ columns to the same scale.